# Why did Deadpool say "Somebody swiped right"?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2

In *Deadpool 2* (2018), Cable uses the last charge on his time-traveling device, 
which he needed for returning to his family:

> **Deadpool:** What's with the creepy, dirty hobo bear?
>
> **Cable:** It's my daughter's teddy bear. Her name's Hope.
>
> *Cable straps Vanessa's token in front of Deadpool's heart.*
>
> **Deadpool:** Well...What are you doing? **Somebody swiped right.**

[image: Cable puts the token on Wade]

Why did he say "Somebody swiped right"?

Answer (score 12):

When Cable is slipping the token, Deadpool is suggesting (not for the first time) that Cable is attracted to him.

The "swipe right" comes from the dating app "Tinder":

> Tinder is a location-based social search mobile app that allows users to **like (swipe right)** or dislike (swipe left) other users and allows users to chat if both parties liked each other in the app (a "match").